# How to update the dynamically selected column in data.table

Tags: r, data.table, dplyr

The target is to use `parse_number()` on the columns which contains "XX" or "YY"
(eliminate all "comma")

```
# DT
DT <- data.table(C1 = c("12","14","94"),XX_C2 = 
c("12,1","14,0","94,1"),XX_C3 = c("52,33","44,9","194,1"),C4 = 
c("124","1","9"),ZZ_C5 = c("1132,3","1442,0","914,2"),ZZ_C5 = 
c("1532,3","1742,9","94,1"))
```

I have the approach like below : (it works)

```
DT <- DT %>% 
  mutate_at(vars(grep("XX|YY",names(.), value = TRUE)), funs(parse_number))
```

How to achieve this in data.table way as `library(dplyr) %>%` is very slow for large data .

```
DT[,parse_number(.SD),.SDcols = list(grep("XX|YY",colnames(DT),value = TRUE))]
```

Get error

```
DT[,grep("XX"|YY",colnames(DT),value = TRUE),with = FALSE]
```

Can select the column dynamically but don't know how to apply `:=` with `parse_number(x)`  on implicitly columns

Comment: Can you express your desire in natural language? Expressing it via a function from an unnamed package is not effective communication. Also ineffective is saying "eliminate comma".  What is the expected result?

Comment: Based on the example, there is no `YY` column in the dataset

Comment: Apologize . "eliminate comma" -- means remove " , " separator of digits .   "XX|YY" is wrong , "XX|ZZ" was what i intended  to write . That was a typo .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If we are using `parse_number` from `readr`, after creating the index of column names that have 'XX or 'ZZ', specify that in the `.SDcols`, loop through the `.SD` (Subset of Data.table), extract the numbers with `readr::parse_number`, and assign (`:=`) the output back to the same columns

```
library(data.table)
nm1 <- grep("XX|ZZ", names(DT))
DT[ , (nm1) := lapply(.SD, parse_number), .SDcols = nm1]
DT
#   C1 XX_C2 XX_C3  C4 ZZ_C5 ZZ_C5
#1: 12   121  5233 124 11323 15323
#2: 14   140   449   1 14420 17429
#3: 94   941  1941   9  9142   941
```

NOTE: In the example, there are two columns with the same name i.e. "ZZ_C5".  It is not recommended to have the same column names as it can create problems later.

```
setnames(DT, make.unique(names(DT)))
```

Comment: Thankyou very much ,perfect .  Even my dirty description and typo of everything. That exactly what i want and i realize that 1. dynamically search the target columns + 2. updated the target columns by :=   , cannot complete in one script .(generally)

Answer (score 3):

You can melt the data to give you a `value` column, which you can then pass through your `parse_number()` function.

```
## defining a 'parse_number' function
parse_number <- function(x) {
    as.numeric(gsub(pattern = ",",".",x))
}

cols <- names(DT)[grepl("^C", names(DT))]
dt <- melt(DT, id.vars = cols)[, value := parse_number(value)][]

dt
#     C1  C4 variable   value
#  1: 12 124    XX_C2   12.10
#  2: 14   1    XX_C2   14.00
#  3: 94   9    XX_C2   94.10
#  4: 12 124    XX_C3   52.33
#  5: 14   1    XX_C3   44.90
#  6: 94   9    XX_C3  194.10
#  7: 12 124    ZZ_C5 1132.30
#  8: 14   1    ZZ_C5 1442.00
#  9: 94   9    ZZ_C5  914.20
# 10: 12 124    ZZ_C5 1532.30
# 11: 14   1    ZZ_C5 1742.90
# 12: 94   9    ZZ_C5   94.10
```

Note:

In your original data you have two columns `ZZ_C5` - may want to check this.

Comment: Thankyou SymbolizAU , that is a new way of thinking to duel with the problem by using melt() function  . But i wondering if it can keep cols which start from ZZ and XX as a column shape but not rows.   Double ZZ_C5 is a typo when i was making the example